# Typed.js - Undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, undefined, typed

I'm trying to use the Typed.js library but it doesn't seem to work. It gives me the following error message in console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The reference in the console is to this line:

```
 $("#typed").typed({
```

The error seems to indicate I haven't included jQuery but I have.

```
<!-- TYPED -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: ["Typed.js is a <strong>jQuery</strong> plugin.", "It <em>types</em> out sentences.", "And then deletes them.", "Try it out!"],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: 'html', // or text
        // defaults to false for infinite loop
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
    });

});

function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }
function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
```

The html:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="post-heading">
                    <h1>Baresso og Starbucks</h1>
                    <h2 class="subheading element">Så mange kalorier smider de rundt</h2>
                    <h2 class="element" id="typed">hej</h2>
                    <span class="meta">Posted by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=176878997&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile">Kristoffer Andreasen</a> on November 24, 2014</span>
                </div>
```

It might be really simple but I just can't figure it out at the moment.
Can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure that the path `js/typed.js` is correct?

Comment: I solved the problem. JQuery was loaded later on the page too. The duplicate caused it to load after the script.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce this kind of issue, we can either

1) "remove" angular script reference, or
2) just place it at the very "late" position, after our modules.

```
Try To Load scripts in the sequence below:-
app.Module
Controller
Interface
angular.js
angular.min.js
app.route
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was using cdn version("`https://cdn.bootcss.com/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js`") it was working fine. But when I was trying the downloaded typed.js from github it was giving the same error.

To solve this I went to the cdn link and copied the page to my typed.js. It solved my problem.